# Google Chrome issue when embedding fontawesome elements on localhost! Not displayed during execution. (with code snippet)

Tags: css, google-chrome, icons, font-awesome

i want to include fontawesome star icons, but they are not shown.

Although I think I have entered fa correctly
So here is a part of my code and a screenshot:

I am using VSCode, XAMPP and PHP with Ajax and MySQL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                    </div>
```

Can u help me with this issue?
Do u need further informations?

[image]

The Stars should be displayed in the red area.

thank you, I am available for your questions!

**update:**

as we found out it is a chrome problem and not from my code.

here is the error message:
[image]

Comment: this is the only icon i need from fontawesome

Comment: Font Awesome is complete overkill, if you only need a star. But I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks! you can also suggest alternatives, maybe i will need more icons from there in the future

Comment: OK, I can see the star, with your code, but you do have the wrong classes. Try this first: `<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>`, and then `<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>`. I think both should work. There might always be something, in your own classes, that prevent the star from shining.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is not working ;(

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so when i open your website, it is empty :o

Comment: Ah, OK. Well, that, more or less, explains it. What browser are you using on which OS? I am using Firefox on Win10.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i am using Google Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: I have Chrome as well, and the stars are shown in there as well.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yeah i tried ms edge right now, and there i can see the stars. Why i have a problem in Chrome? Thats strange

Comment: Check the [console in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/), do you see any error messages?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i edited the question with the error message, hope u can see

Comment: Ah, you're running the code on your local host. CORS doesn't like that. I never do that, so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: My suggestion is to download the Font Awesome CSS file and put it on your localhost. In other words: host it yourself, then CORS won't bother you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No Problem! i thought i had an issue in my code, but it is working with MS Edge, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found out, it is not my code that is the problem.
CORS has problems processing fontawesome CSS file in use with the localhost.

**solution:**

- use another browser, it worked for me in ms edge
- download the Font Awesome CSS file and put it on your localhost.  In
  other words: host it yourself, then CORS won't bother you

Special thanks to @KIKOSoftware